# How to assign a task to a method

Tags: c#

Consider this code below :

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
       
        // what is this ?? 
        async Task Something() =>await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Something");
        
        await methodX(Something);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async Task methodX(Func<Task> func)
    {
        
        await func();
       
    }
}
```

i'm not familar with the syntax used in this line here :

```
 async Task Something() =>await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Something");
```

is "Something" a method,a delegate or what
i'm used to Lambda expression but not this syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
async Task Something() =>await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Something");
```

is a [*local function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that uses [Expression body definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#expression-body-definitions). It's the same as doing this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    int AddTwo(int a) => a + 2;

    Console.WriteLine(AddTwo(4)); // prints 6;
}
```

`Something` is a method ("Function") that returns a Task. That's why the method itself is passed to `methodX`, which asks for `Func<Task>`.

Instead of inline, you could have had it at the type level.

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await methodX(Something);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task Something() => await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Something");

    public static async Task methodX(Func<Task> func)
    {
        await func();
    }
}
```

It would behave the same.